# How to validate that a given string will work as a valid sql type

Tags: java, sql, regex

I am building an application that includes the ability for the user to enter data into a database.
If a user enters some text, for example they try to enter a date, I want to be able to validate that the string they entered can be executed in an SQL query with out a problem.

I am coding in java, so I'm wondering if there are any small libraries out there that do this, or if I should use different reg-exes to do the validation.

I don't want to rely on the database to do validation because (a) it could be slow if it is far away, and (b) I may want to implment some other custom validation rules (or let the user do it) and want to keep all my validation in a box.

Thanks

Comment: Regular expression validation?

Comment: http://springinpractice.com/2008/07/17/annotation-based-validation-with-the-spring-bean-validation-framework/

Comment: Could you use exception handling to test if the SQL string runs or not?

Comment: so, i don't want to have the SQL server do the validation for reasons listed above. also, the interface to the SQL server is wrapped up in our application, so it isn't exactly easy.

Comment: Sorry, I was actually wrong about the PreparedStatement. This actually sends the query to the database for pre-compilation. I think what you need is an sql precompiler. Not sure if anyone exposes that as an api.

Comment: I'm sorry, I glanced over that part.  You might still want to consider that option. I doubt it would be slow for the database to throw an error based because of invalid SQL and you could simply implement your own validation from the client side.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. Do you want to let the users enter a SQL query, to be executed as is on the database? Or do you want to let them enter a String that you will store in some comuln in the database? If the latter, any string is a valid string, unless it's too large to fit in the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you shouldn't rely on the database's definition of a date.  Instead, you should declare a valid application format (e.g., MM/DD/YY) and use regular expressions, a library or your own code to validate the users input and then perform a transformation from the specified format to the database format (e.g., MM/DD/YY -> YY/MM/DD).

If you are using an ORM, it will perform this conversion for you on specific types (like Java's data classes) based on the underlying database.  Otherwise, you have to do this yourself, but it's best to seperate the input validation from the database specific transformation.

Comment: close enough answer for me, and good advice on the ORM, which we are using. thanks.